# How to get firebug to break on exception?

Tags: firebug

I'm using Firebug 1.5.4.  When I reference an undefined variable or some such, it breaks right where the problem occurs, and throws me into the debug view where I can see the stack and inspect variables.

However, when I throw my own exception, it just takes me to the console and prints out "uncaught exception: blah".  I'd like it to break and let me inspect variables.  How can I tell Firebug to do this?

Comment: So did that work for you, then? More problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The respondent was helpful but neglected something very key I was missing; the window.onerror event.  Here is the full code:

```
 window.onerror = function(msg) {
   debugger;
 }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to give me a useful stack trace still. My stack just shows the onerror() call, not the code where the exception occurred.

Comment: Try this:

var arg = arguments[4];
s.stack;

This is while you are still breakpointed in window.onerror

Answer (score 10):

Install Firebug 1.6b1 http://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.6X, Firebug > Console > "the exception" Click the breakpoint selector in the left column. Run your code. Firebug breaks on that line.

Or Firebug > Console > [||] breaks on next error

Comment: If the exception only occurs rarely on a very commonly called line of code, though, that gets annoying very quickly.

Comment: In Firebug 1.7 it is named Track Throw/Catch

Answer (score 7):

Call *Web Developer Debugger* (Tools => Web Developer => Debugger or **Ctrl + Shift + S**), click gear icon and check "Pause on exception":

[image]

Or execute `debugger;` in *Web Developer Console*!

Official *Web Developer Debugger* docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger

Answer (score 0):

Put a `debugger;` statement in your code or use the `Script` tab of firebug to click on a line number (which inserts a breakpoint).

If you only want to do it when you throw an exception, you could put the debugger statement in a `catch` block.

Comment: It is not feasible to use a breakpoint in this case since the exception might not occur until the 100th time through the code, and I don't want to step through it 100 times.  I am only interested if/when an exception occurs.  But tell me more about this "debugger;" thing...

Comment: Ok so when you catch your exception, in the `catch` block, but `debugger;` in there (or insert a breakpoint there in firebug). That way you'll only get dropped into the debugger when the exception happens.

Comment: In the context of your question the code `debugger;` is simply the same as inserting a breakpoint in firebug on that line.

Comment: The question is not making sense. There isn't 100 times here. You said you are throwing an exception: so that is where you set a breakpoint or put debugger; statement or console.error() or what ever. Unless you hit the exception 100 times, in which case you have more problems than we can solve here.