# Canvas context.fillText throws “An invalid or illegal string was specified”

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I’ve got a Heisenbug in my code. It only appears every now and then and can’t be triggered deliberately.

FireBug throws an exception like “An invalid or illegal string was specified” at me and refers to a different line every time.

I’m using FireFox 10.0. The website is located at http://www.roboter-club-hamburg.de. I’ve already tried with FireQuery but that interferes with my code so it’s no option.

---

I’ve tracked it down to a line that looks like this:

```
context.fillText("[[*longtitle]]", x + 4, y + h + 15, w);
```

I’m using MODX CMS to build that website (that’s where `[[*longtitle]]` and `[[*id]]` and stuff come from; they are template placeholders).

Here’s the full function that this line is in:

```js
($("imagecvs-[[*id]]").ready(function() {
    var canvas = $("#imagecvs-[[*id]]").get(0);
    if (canvas.getContext) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();

    img.src = "[[*Photo]]";

    var scale = 0.6;
    var ratio = img.width / img.height;

    var w = Math.min(img.width * scale, 120);
    var h = w / ratio;
    var x = 0;
    var y = (canvas.height / 2.0) - (h / 2.0);

    var deg = -8;
    var rad = (deg * Math.PI / 180);
    // y += (h / 2) * -Math.sin( rad );
    context.rotate(rad);

    context.fillStyle = "#FFF";
    context.fillRect(x - 5, y - 5, w + 10, h + 30);
    context.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h);

    context.font = "Italic Bold 10px Serif";
    context.textAlign = "left";
    context.textBaseline = "ideographic";
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    context.fillText("This is a test", x + 4, y + h + 15, w); // Exception thrown here; even with 'This is a test'
    }
    return true;
  }));
```

Comment: Paste your code into [JS Lint](http://jslint.com/) and fix the errors it reports (or come back and ask questions about *why* JS Lint complains about an error if you don't understand something it reports).

Comment: Well, it's not just a Heisenbug. It's also running away from me. Now I've got the same exception in a totally different place. Here is what the error message looks like in FireBug now: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/17/jqueryerror.jpg/

Comment: @DavidThomas That would probably work if only it was without jQuery. It complains about any jQuery specific instruction.

Comment: @SeveQ, consider posting your code into a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and then (with your jQuery in the 'JavaScript' pane) hit the 'JS Lint' button. It's never generated any problems for me when I've pasted jQuery, since it conforms to the expectations, and syntax, of JavaScript.

Comment: @DavidThomas alright, that tells me that my code is valid.

Comment: And the location FireBug points at is jumping around. It must be something totally different. The exception is always the same but the location is different everytime the bug occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I've found the cause of this bug. It's been caused by the fact that the image (img) sometimes was not completely loaded at the time the script asked for its width and height. Hence both were NaN and the script crashed (fillText apparently doesn't work with a width of NaN).

Now, all I've done to solve this problem is to move the drawing steps into the onload callback of img. That works. This Heisenbug is no more.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't now how to do that in FireBug, but in the WebKit Web Inspector ([here for FireBug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754604/how-to-get-firebug-to-break-on-exception)) you can choose to break on exceptions.

Than you can look at the call stack to see where your code is calling this JQuery code. I don't think that the problem is in JQuery. You probably pass invalid arguments to a function.